# Prove existence of a maximum of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $a ∈] − 2, 2[$ , solve the problem:

$max \ x^2 + y^2 + axy − 2x − 2y $

where $(x, y) ∈ R^2$

How do I show that the maximum exists? Does there even exist a maximum, since for $a< 2$ the function is convex?

Comment: What is the (P) for? But whatever the value of $a$, you can get the value as large as you like by taking $x$ large and $y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist, since setting $y=0$ gives $x^2-2x$, which blows up as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$.